# Aptana 3 - HTML Validation in PHP files

Tags: php, html, validation, syntax, aptana

Is there a way to enable syntax validation for HTML code that's inside a .php file? I've tried  checking both "web" and "php" for project natures and adding file type associations too.

Right now when I make any html error within a php file, it gives no error/warning whatsoever. I have the doctype set to html5, so it SHOULD return a warning at least right?

Answer (score 0):

No. Since you are writing to a `.php` file, Aptana will only validate `PHP` syntax, **not** `HTML`. If you're having a problem with `HTML syntax`, write your `HTML` in a `.html` file and transfer it over. (simpliest, most obvious way)